# Drupal 7 theming: region error

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

this is in my theme.info file of my Drupal theme:

```
regions[conf_modules] = Configurator: modules
```

I'm using multiple templates for different node types. In one of them I'd like this region/block to show up. So I've put this in node--configurator.tpl.php:

```
<?php print render($page['conf_modules']); ?>
```

In the Drupal administration panel I have assigned a views block to the region, but on the node--configurator.tpl.php pages, the views block is not shown. Am I using render() properly? What's going wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In node templates, `$page` is simply a status variable that is:

> True if the node is being displayed by itself as a page.

However, you can add regions to the page for specific content types through your `page.tpl.php` if you like.  Something like below should work if placed in `page.tpl.php`:

```
<?php
  if ($node->type == 'CONTENT_TYPE') {
    print render($page['conf_modules']);
  }
?>
```